# 1970-80's Roadmaster bike makes a clicking noise when turning right

Tags: road-bike, maintenance, wheels, vintage, headset

A 70's/80's Roadmaster Pursuit bike makes a clicking noise when turning right. It doesn't make any noise when riding straight or turning left. It doesn't seem to matter how close the turn is. I have checked the headset and all bearings are fine. I checked the axle and that is fine too. I cleaned and greased both and still makes the noise.  Any suggestions as to what else could it be causing it?

Comment: Good work so far, but break it down some more.  Does the front wheel click when turning right, or is it the handlebars turning to the right that click?

Comment: If you lift the front of the bike off the ground and spin the wheel while standing still, does it click?  This is testing the axle/cones/bearings and whether weight on the wheel affects it.

Comment: As a test, flip the wheel in the forks and see if the clicking stays on the right, moves to the left turn, or vanishes completely.  Be mindful tread differences, and braking might be affected, so this is for testing.

Comment: Also look for things like sprues coming off the tyre, that only hit the frame/fork when turning.  Brake cables or gear cables paths change too - they can tap on frames at different turn angles.

Comment: Obviously, the bike just wants to be used on an indoor track!

Comment: Where does the sound seem to come from, and what is the "tempo"?

Comment: (The most likely cause is the rear tire brushing the frame when the bike is tilted to one side -- will produce a "bzzzzt bzzzzt" sound.  This might be due to a "tacoed" wheel, an improperly mounted tire, a loose bearing, or not having the axle squarely in the dropouts.)

Comment: Sometimes this can be cable housing ends crunching around in the stops. You can try putting a drop of lube on them.

Comment: As @Criggie suggested, I flipped the front wheel and the clicking noise is gone. Turning right or left, no more clicking. ..

Comment: OK something's wrong with the bearings in the front hub.  Time for a rebuild - clean out the old grease, and fit new bearings.  It'll take time more than cost.